# Mac: Skype cancel file transfer without starting skype

Tags: skype

I accidently dragged and dropped the wrong file into the wrong group
Panicked and closed down skype.
I deleted the original file, *but the file is still sending when I log on.*

I assume this means its cached somewhere.

How do I cancel / remove the cached file/ BEFOREE I log on?

**Update**
What I have done is moved my User/Library/Application Data/Skype folder for now.Tonight when I get time I'll try and work out which file it is in the cache. And regardless I might just do an "AppCleaner" type uninstall of skype and start afresh.

Comment: `1.` Disconnect your computer from the network. If you connect via wireless then temporarily turn off your WAP. If you can't do that then turn of wireless in the BIOS or hard switch if available. `2.` Log on. `3.` Find the file. `4.` Delete it. `5.` Reconnect to network. `6.` Profit!

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: If he disconnects from the internet then he can't log into Skype to attempt to locate the file.

Comment: Windows Skype shows a Cancel button when it is sending a file. Even for tiny files you will still get time to cancel because before the actual file is transferred, (1) the recipient(s) has to accept and choose save location (even in groups). (2) there will be a slight connecting delay after recipient accepts. I find no reason to panic like what you did, unless Mac Skype operates differently.

Comment: ^some people had auto download setup. After I disconnected from the net there was no way to cancel the overall download.

Answer (score 1):

First,move that file from that place which is accidently dragged n dropped!,then find skype folder in Appdata(as far as i know,it is in local and roaming folder too,but main is roaming's skype folder)then try to find your file there (match the size too,may be file name has been changed)and delete it!